# Will an integer combination of some number of copies of the set of powers of 2 and the set of powers of 3 always have natural density 0?

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics, diophantine-equations

Consider a Diophantine equation of the form

$$(c_1 2^{x_1} + \dots + c_n 2^{x_n}) + (c_{n+1} 3^{x_{n+1}} + \dots + c_m 3^{x_m}) = y$$

where $x_1, \dots, x_m, y$ are our variables (here $x_1, \dots, x_m$ are required to be nonnegative but $y$ is not) and $c_1, \dots, c_m$ are integer constants. My question is whether the projection of the solution set onto $y$, i.e. the set $Y$ of all $y$ such that we may find $x_1, \dots, x_m$ satisfying the equation, will always have natural density zero, i.e. $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|Y \cap [-k, k]|}{|\mathbb{Z} \cap [-k, k]|} = 0$.

If we assume $c_1, \dots, c_n$ are positive this is trivial; the expression $\frac{|Y \cap [-k, k]|}{|\mathbb{Z} \cap [-k, k]|}$ decays exponentially. But without this assumption, the problem seems to me to be much deeper.

An early step toward this result is this: if we restrict ourselves to the specific equation $2^{x_1} - 3^{x_2} = y$, then this is known to once again give us exponential decay. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116852), from which we can easily compute the required bound. But this is nontrivial and is also the simplest of an array of increasingly more complex cases.

Because of this, I suspect that my overall conjecture is not known to be true. Is there however any known counterexample? And if not, how inaccessible is the result likely to be? Should I expect a number theorist to figure this out within a few years, or is this one of those Collatz-like conjectures where our current toolset will never get us close?

Comment: I think the magic words here are "Schmidt's subspace theorem" and it's application by people like Evertse to sums $c_1u_1+\cdots+c_nu_n$,where the $c_i$ are fixed integers, and the $u_i$ are $S$-units for some finite set of primes $S$. In your case, you're taking $S=\{2,3\}$, although you're restricting further.

Comment: Do you have a specific reference for that work by Evertse? I'm not a number theorist by "trade" (I'm in logic), so I am admittedly a bit of a fish out of water here (for instance I had to look up what $S$-units are, though I might have seen that when I took algebraic number theory a few years back and simply forgotten).

Comment: (MR766298) Evertse, Jan-Hendrik, On sums of $S$-units and linear recurrences, *Compositio Math.* **53** (1984), 225--244. But I don't know that this will have exactly what you want, it's just that these sorts of techniques will (sometimes) yield estimates for the size of linear combinations of the sort you're studying.