# How big are small inverse powers of 2 mod powers of 3?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, characteristic-p

Let $a \bmod b$ take value as an integer in $[0, b)$. For any $T \ge 1$, for what $R \in [0, 3^n)$ is
$$\min \{2^{-t}\bmod 3^n: t =1, \dotsc, T\} := \min A_T > R?$$

When $T$ is fixed as $n$ increases, $R$ can be taken obviously as $\Theta(3^n)$. If $T = 2 \cdot 3^{n-1}$, then of course $R$ must be 0. However, I'm interested in the case where, say, $T = \Theta(n)$, and I want to say that we can take $R = \Theta(3^n/{\operatorname{poly}(n)})$. As a concrete example,

> If $T = n$, then, for sufficiently large $n$, can we take $R > c 3^n / n^2$ for some constant $c$?

There are two pieces of evidences for this:

1. Modeling $2^{-t}\bmod 3^n$ as random numbers, the probability that $A_T$ intersects $[1, R]$ is $RT/3^n$. If $T = \Theta(n)$ and $R = \Theta(3^n/n^2)$, for example, then this probability goes to 0 with $n$.
2. I have done numerical simulation for the $T=n$ case and found what looks like $R = \Theta(3^n/n^2)$.

There are prior works along the lines of 1, especially in the literature for pseudorandomness, for example by [Korobov - On the distribution of digits in periodic fractions (1972)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1972v018n04ABEH001870) and [Shparlinski - Distribution of exponential functions modulo a prime power (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2014.04.010), of the form
\begin{equation}
\lvert A_T \cap [1, R]\rvert = RT/3^n + O(\text{error}). \tag{$*$}\label{star}
\end{equation}
However, the error term in these works always grows with $n$, whereas in my scenario I want it to vanish with $n$. I've also looked into the proof and very early on their techniques would preclude an error term that vanishes with $n$.

In addition, taking *inverse powers* of 2 seems special, since our claim is obvious not true for positive powers of 2, so universal bounds like \eqref{star} would seem to be too blunt.

I would appreciate any pointers to other relevant literature or techniques, as well as an outright solution of this problem.

### Edit: [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem)

[Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) gives an answer to a variant of my question, though unfortunately not my question itself. For example, as discussed in this [mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116840/distance-between-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3),
$$|2^T - 3^n| \ge \frac{3^n}{c n^C}$$
for $2^T < 3^n$ and some constants $c, C>0$, which implies
$$\{2^t \bmod 3^n: t=1, \ldots, T\} \cap \{3^n - r: r = 1, \ldots, R\} = \emptyset$$
when $T < n \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ and $R < \frac{3^n}{c n^C}$. This is similar to my question except that this is *upper* bounding *positive* powers of 2 away from $3^n$ rather than *lower* bounding *negative* powers of 2 away from 0; and, of course, this approach only works for $T = n \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} + O(1)$ instead of the more general $T = O(n)$.

We can reformulate my question in the style above as: For any integer $n, k \ge 0$,
$$\left(\frac{3^n+1}{2}\right)^t - k 3^n > \frac{3^n}{c n^C}$$
for some absolute constants $c, C> 0$ whenever the LHS is positive and $t \le n$.
I've tried applying Baker's theorem directly to this formulation but it does not seem to work because Baker's theorem can't really deal with the non-exponential $k$. I've also tried adapting Baker's proof to my case, but so far it has not been working out.

Comment: If you can’t beat Shparlinski, it will require something big