# Simple estimation of difference of powers of 2 and powers of 3?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, transcendental-number-theory

**1. Question**

How to get from the formulas

$$ \left| \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} - \frac{p}{q} \right| < c_a\frac{1}{q^{B_a}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.1)$$

and / or

$$ \left| \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} - \frac{p}{q} \right| \geq c_b\frac{1}{q^{B_b}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.2)$$

to the formula

$$ \left| 3^p - 2^q \right| \geq c_r\frac{1}{q^{B_r}}3^p\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.3)$$

with constants $c_a, c_b, B_a, B_b \in \mathbb{R}$ given and $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$?

It is also important for me how exactly $c_r, B_r \in \mathbb{R}$ depend on the other constants $c_a, c_b, B_a$, and $B_b$. All 6 constants are > 0 and $B_a, B_b \in [2, 8)$.

The lower bound in (1.3) is claimed by https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/ (proposition 3 and corollary 4) . Terry Tao uses (1.2) with $\geq$ instead of (1.1) with $<$. Maybe both inequalities are required to prove (1.3) for the two cases $3^p > 2^q$ and $3^p < 2^q$.

Something very similar is [the answer by user Lierre to the MO question distance between powers of 2 and powers of 3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116844/163727), but I would like to see more detailed steps and how to calculate the constants in (1.3).

**2. Ansatz A**

\begin{align}
3^p - 2^q &= 3^p - (3^{\log_3(2)})^q\\
          &= 3^p - 3^{q\cdot \log_3(2)}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^{q\cdot \log_3(2) - p + p}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^p\cdot3^{q\cdot \log_3(2) - p}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^p\cdot3^{q\cdot(\log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q})}\\
          &= 3^p(1 - 3^{q\cdot(\log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q})}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.1)\\
\end{align}

Note that

\begin{align}
3^p > 2^q &\iff \log_3(3^p) > \log_3(2^q)\\
          &\iff p > q\log_3(2)\\
          &\iff \frac{p}{q} > \log_3(2)\\
          &\iff 0 > \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q}\\
          &\iff \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q} < 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.2)\\
\end{align}

and analogously

$$2^q > 3^p \iff \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q} > 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.3)$$.

**3. Ansatz B**

\begin{align}
3^p - 2^q &= 3^p(1 - \frac{2^q}{3^p})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - \frac{(e^{\log2})^q}{(e^{\log3})^p})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - \frac{e^{q\log2}}{e^{p\log3}})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - e^{q\log2 - p\log3}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3.1)\\
\end{align}

Comment: cross post from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510835/simple-estimation-of-separation-of-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev thanks! Corrected.

Comment: Just for information: I'm starting a discussion of installing a [BigList] here in MO , where classical or new such bounds are referenced and/or detailed wrt their analytical derivations. See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5423/7710

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Hey, nice to see you and welcome back! :)

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about bounding $e^x$ such as $e^x \geq 1 + x$.

For example, when $2^q>3^p$ (ie. $\log_3 2>\frac{p}q$), from (1.2) we have
$$q\log 2 \geq c_b \frac{\log 3}{q^{B_b-1}} + p\log 3,$$
which under exponentiation translates to
$$2^q \geq e^{c_b \frac{\log 3}{q^{B_b-1}}}3^p.$$
Then
$$2^q - 3^p \geq \big(e^{c_b \frac{\log 3}{q^{B_b-1}}}-1\big)3^p \geq c_b \frac{\log 3}{q^{B_b-1}}3^p.$$

The other cases are considered similarly.