# Powers of $3$ close to powers of $2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, music-theory

The musical scale of $5$ fifths has good temperament because $3^5$ is quite close to a power of $2$, namely $2^8-3^5=13$, and I suspect that in the subsequent powers of $3$ none is so close to a power of $2$. Analogously, our usual chromatic scale with $12$ notes has good temperament because $3^{12}$ is very close to a power of $2$, namely $3^{12}-2^{19}=7153$.

Does the Diophantine equation $|3^n-2^m|\le 13$ admit a solution with $n>5$?

Does the Diophantine equation $|3^n-2^m|\le 7153$ admit a solution with $n>12$?

A direct inspection of the first $35$ scales of fifths with good temperament shows that any such solution must be $n>10^{18}$.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481119/87355

Comment: the difference grows exponentially with increasing $n$, see the [estimate](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116844/11260) $\left| 3^n - 2^ m\right| = \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{3^n}{n} \right)$ for $n\gg 1$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The estimate you quote is an upper bound for infinitely many $n$'s. Exponential lower bounds are available for all $n$, see e.g. my post below.

Comment: Also related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116840/distance-between-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but it's worth noting that some musicians have explored the division of the octave into [19 equal steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19_equal_temperament), noting that it closely approximates thirds as well as fourths and fifths.

Comment: @TimothyChow. Emilio Gagliardo used to have an office in the Math Department of the University of Pavia, with a soundproof door, where he would practice compositions on such a scale.

Comment: Also 31 equal steps gives a very good approximation to quarter comma meantone.

Comment: why is $3^2-2^3=1$ ignored? It's the smallest difference.

Comment: Maybe because that amounts to approximating a perfect fifth with a diminished fifth - the "diabolus in musica".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Ellison (1971)](http://www.numdam.org/article/STNB_1970-1971____A10_0.pdf), see MR0417051, proved that
$$|3^n-2^m|>1.8^m,\qquad m>27.$$
From this bound and the SAGE program below, we see that the only solution of $|3^n-2^m|\leq 13$ with $n\geq 5$ is $(m,n)=(8,5)$, and the only solution of $|3^n-2^m|\leq 7153$ with $n\geq 12$ is $(m,n)=(19,12)$.

```
for m in range(28):
    for n in range(5,18):
        if abs(3^n-2^m)<14:
            print(m,n,3^n-2^m)
for m in range(28):
    for n in range(12,18):
        if abs(3^n-2^m)<7154:
            print(m,n,3^n-2^m)
```

**P.S.** It is worth pointing out that the solutions $(8,5)$ and $(19,12)$ above correspond to the continued fraction approximants $8/5$ and $19/12$ of $\log 3/\log 2$.

Comment: Note that the ideal base in Ellison's result is $2e^{-1/10}$ which is slightly over 1.8.  There is a followup paper by Tijdeman MR0325549 which gets an asymptotically tighter, but not effective bound. (I think that one can be made effective though.)

Comment: @JoshuaZ Sure, I used $1.8$ for stylistic reasons. There is a better effective bound by Rhin (1987), see MR1017910. His theorem gives that $\|m\log 2+n\log 3\|\geq\max(m,n)^{-13.3}$ as long as $\max(m,n)\geq 2$.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the Rhin result. Good to know.

Comment: @JoshuaZ I was lazy to work out what effective lower bound follows for $|3^n-2^m|$ from the result of Rhin (1987).

Comment: [MR0417051](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=417051): Ellison - On a theorem of S. Sivasankaranarayana Pillai.  Do you know if there is an exposition of the proof available anywhere widely accessible?

Comment: @LSpice I don't know of such an exposition, but I am no expert. The closest I have read is Baker's book "Transcendental number theory". Theorem 3.1 (Baker's theorem) shows that $\|m\log 2+n\log 3\|\geq\max(m,n)^{-C}$ with some unspecified constant $C>0$. Perhaps you will find Tao's notes useful where Proposition 6 is a weaker version of this special case of Baker's theorem: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/

Comment: Instead of two loops isn't it faster to do one loop and check integers near `$m=\log_2(3^n)$?

Comment: @joro The running time is faster by some unnoticable time, while programming it takes a bit longer.

Comment: Looking at Ellison's inequality, I'd suppose that $ \lim\inf |3^n-2^m|^{1/m}$ cannot be smaller than $2$, otherwise stated, there should be only finitely many pairs (m,n) such that $ |3^n-2^m|<2^m$. Maybe this is even obvious?

Comment: (and note that the quoted bounds by Rhin and Baker are not about the *difference* $|3^n-2^m|$ but about $\log(2^m3^n)$.)

Comment: @Wolfgang Ellison's inequality implies that $\inf |3^n-2^m|^{1/m}>1.8$. I am certain that Rhin's inequality (and in fact Baker's original inequality) implies $\liminf |3^n-2^m|^{1/m}\geq 2$, but I am not certain that it implies $\inf |3^n-2^m|^{1/m}\geq 2$. As I told earlier, I was lazy to work out the precise numeric consequences of Rhin's inequality. The quoted bound by Rhin and Baker are about $\|m\log 2-n\log 3\|$ where $\|x\|$ is the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer. They imply lower bounds for $|3^n-2^m|$, because if $3^n/2^m\approx 1$, then $m\log 2\approx n\log 3$.

Comment: @GHfromMO sure enough. Of course, it can be only about $\lim\inf$, never about $\inf$, there may always be a finite number of exceptions. And I would think that $2$ is best possible.

Comment: @Wolfgang In fact $|3^n-2^m|$ is infinitely often smaller than a constant times $2^m/m$. This happens whenever $|\log 2/\log 3-n/m|\leq 1/m^2$. Also, $|3^n-2^m|$ exceeds $2^m/m^C$ for all $m\geq 2$, where $C>0$ is a suitable constant, hence indeed $\liminf |3^n-2^m|^{1/m}=2$.

Comment: The denominators in 8/5 and 19/12 are related to the pentatonic and the chromatic scales.  The continued fraction expansion of $\log_2(3)$ spits out these numbers as convergents.  The next convergent is 65/41.  Harry Partch was close when he started composing with a 43-tone scale.

Comment: @GHfromMO if I got it right, the $||m \ln 2 + n \ln 3||$ result gives forbidden region $(-\frac{3^n}{n^{13.3}}; \frac{2^m}{n^{13.3}})$